# Casting a custom class to a dict in python

Tags: python

Perhaps I'm overlooking something simple, but I would like to cast an instance of a custom class as a dictionary in python (for the sake of readability), but haven't got an inkling as to how.  To explain in pseudocode, I would like to be able to do this:

```
class A:
   # class things...

a = A()
b = dict(a)
```

where I have defined what `b` will be within `A`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Usually, this is accomplished with a custom method.  `a.todict()` or similar

Comment: is there a problem with `b = a.getdict()`?

Comment: What do you expect from b? If all you want is access to a's namespace {attributes:values}, you can use vars(a) or a.__dict__.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a custom method getDict(), which is what I have written while waiting for an answer.  It just seems...sloppy.

Comment: @sidi has a decent answer, but I need this action to recurse (i.e to get `__dict__` of members of `a`).

Comment: another name: `a.as_dict()`. `__iter__()` usually provides a shallow traversal. `a.walk()` could be used for a deep (recursive) version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define `__iter__`, it'll Just Work(tm):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __iter__(self):
        return vars(self).iteritems()
```

gives

```
>>> A(2,3)
<__main__.A object at 0x101ea70d0>
>>> dict(A(2,3))
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}
```

and you can return or yield whatever you like.  That said, I second the suggestion in the comments that you should really just implement a `.to_dict()` method instead, as often `__iter__` is too useful for other purposes to waste on this one.

Comment: +1, Beat me to it. That said, this might all be overkill, as it appears that OP could simply be happy with `vars(a)`.

Comment: @Lattyware: or we can split the difference and use a custom `__str__` or `__repr__` as @tcaswell suggested if readability is the concern and not so much with the `dict` itself.

Comment: @sidi Also gives a good answer in the comments (`__str__` and `__repr__` do not suffice here).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are able to use an import collection, like this

```py
class B(collections.MutableMapping):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.b = dict()

   def __iter__(self):
      return iter(self.b)

    def keys(self):
      return self.b.keys()

    def items(self):
      return self.b.items()

    def values(self):
      return self.b.values()
```

or another suggestion [How to implement own custom dict class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129922/how-to-implement-own-custom-dict-class-in-python)

Comment: While this would allow instances to be used as the argument to a `dict()` call, it merely echoes the instance variable `b`, which is already a dictionary, and which would have to be maintained by the object. It's not obvious exactly what the questioner wants, but it seems likely that the content of the dictionary should somehow reflect the contents of the instance.