# How to implement own custom dict class in python

Tags: python

I am learning classes in python and am fiddling around with creating my own version of `defaultdict` from `collections` module. Here's what I have tried:-

```
class Mydict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self.key = []
        return []
```

Here's the output from interactive shell:-

```
>>> d = Mydict()
>>> d['x']
#outputs []
>>> d['x'].extend([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> print(d)
# Outputs {}
```

I do not understand why does it not store the key `x` in the `d` object? What do I miss?

Comment: `self.key` definitely won't work, because you are touching the instance attribute *literally* named `key`.

Comment: You need to assign to `self[key]` instead of `self.key`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

To get the stored value returned instead of new list:

```
In [143]: class Mydict(dict):
     ...:     def __missing__(self, key):
     ...:         self.__setitem__(key, [])
     ...:         return self[key]
     ...:     

In [144]: d = Mydict()

In [145]: d[2].extend([1, 2, 3])

In [146]: d[2]
Out[146]: [1, 2, 3]
```

---

`dict` uses `__setitem__` to set key-value pairs, so you need to use that instead of setting attributes:

```
In [113]: class Mydict(dict):
     ...:     def __missing__(self, key):
     ...:         self.__setitem__(key, [])
     ...:         return []
     ...:   

In [114]: d = Mydict()

In [115]: d[1]
Out[115]: []

In [116]: d
Out[116]: {1: []}
```

---

FWIW, you can use `d.__dict__` or `vars(d)` to get the attributes dict you set via usual manners:

```
In [117]: class Mydict(dict):
     ...:     def __missing__(self, key):
     ...:         self.__setattr__(key, 'foo')
     ...:         self.__setitem__(key, 'bar')
     ...:         return []
     ...:   

In [118]: d = Mydict()

In [119]: d['x']
Out[119]: []

In [120]: d
Out[120]: {'x': 'bar'}

In [121]: vars(d)
Out[121]: {'x': 'foo'}
```

Comment: tried this, it works but partially.  I mean `d[2].extend([1,5,4,8,7,5])`  and then `print(d[2])` prints `{2:[]}`. How to get the extended list reflected in the `2` key??

Comment: @Gsbansal10 You need to return the saved value instead of a new list; check my edits.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an *attribute* instead of an *item*:

```
self.key = []    # attribute named key
self[key] = bar  # item stored for key
```

You are also not returning the list stored on `self`, but create and return *another* list:

```
return []         # return a new list
return self[key]  # return the stored list
```

---

In your `__missing__` method, use `self[key]` to store an item on `self` for the given `key` and return it:

```
class Mydict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = new_item = []  # create and store a new list
        return new_item            # return the newly created list
```

This ensures that you can directly modify the newly added item:

```
>>> d = Mydict()
>>> d['x']
[]
>>> d['x'].extend([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> d
{'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `self.key = []` doesn't do what you think it does. What you want is to add an item to the dict, but what that actually does is create a new attribute of the Mydict instance called `key` and gives it the value `[]`. To see this

```
>>> d = Mydict()
>>> d['x']
[]
>>> d.key
[]
```

This will do what you expect:

```
class Mydict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self.__setitem__(key,[])
        return []
```

Answer (score -1):

dict is for key value pair, and use update to add values

```
>>> d = Mydict()
>>> d.update({ "a" : 1, "b" : 2 })
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d.update({ "c" : 3, "d" : 4 })
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
>>>
```